# Get list of Chat group using XMPPFramework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

I am trying to fetch the list of available chat groups in my `Ejabbered server` with the help of `XMPPFramework`. Following is my code to fetch the list of Chat Group.

```
- (void) getChatGroupList{
    XMPPJID *servrJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"conference.Server"];
    XMPPIQ *iq = [XMPPIQ iqWithType:@"get" to:servrJID];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:[[self xmppStream] myJID].full];
    NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query"];
    [query addAttributeWithName:@"xmlns" stringValue:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"];
    [iq addChild:query];
    [[self xmppStream] sendElement:iq];
}
```

In response I am getting following XML inside `didReceiveIQ`

```
<presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="username@Server/38489493512952747921478847202003609" to="username@ Server/38489493512952747921478847202003609"><priority>24</priority><x xmlns="vcard-temp:x:update"><photo/></x><c xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps" hash="sha-1" node="https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework" ver="VyOFcFX6+YNmKssVXSBKGFP0BS4="/></presence>
```

Exact name of the group I can't see in the response. Can anyone help what is missing here or How can I get list of Group name and list of users inside each group?

Comment: in which delegate method you are checking response ??? b'cus there are may response get in your `didReceiveIQ` so you have to handle different response based on type of iQ.

Answer (score 0):

Have you figure what happened?

From what I see, your request looks OK, but the response should be for other request.

And not sure what version XMPPFramework you are using, in the latest, there is a `XMPPMUC` class in `XEP-0045`.  You can call `discoverRoomsForServiceNamed` to do the same stuff.  Just make sure to implement `XMPPMUCDelegate` when you use it.

Comment: Ok. I tried to implement code for MUC Like this xmppMuc = [[XMPPMUC alloc] init];
    [xmppMuc addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [xmppMuc discoverRoomsForServiceNamed:@"192.168.1.76"]; But It never reaches to didDiscoverRooms or failedToDiscoverRoomsForServiceNamed. Any other setup is required?

Comment: In MUC, the service name is xxx.host, by default is conference.host.  And I think you need to activate(xmppStream) too

Comment: Actually I am new to XMPP and not getting exactly what you are saying. Can you please share any example link if you have? Or any document which I can refer?

Comment: In your case, you should call " [xmppMuc discoverRoomsForServiceNamed:@"conference.192.168.1.76"];".
The XMPP doc is very useful, http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#disco-rooms.  And the source code of XMPPMUC is here, https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/tree/master/Extensions/XEP-0045.